# Como instalar Laravel, Wordpress, Composer, Postgres, Msql, Apache Tomcat, Sublimetext u otras herramientas

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, apache

A medida que aprendía nuevas herramientas de desarrollo me vi en la situación en la cual cambiaba de equipo tenía que instalar nuevamente todas las herramientas que usaba y por una cuestión de recordar todos los comandos.
Busque la forma de registrarlo.

La mejor forma fue usando un script a base de bash.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que descubras docker. La flexibilidad que necesitas es justo la ventaja que ofrece trabajar con contenedores...

Una vez que tengas instalado docker en tu equipo, encapsular las aplicaciones que necesites en contenedores o descargarte estos de su repo oficial, hace que traerte estas aplicaciones a tu pc sea simplemente cuestión de un comando.

Por lo pronto te dejo la web oficial: https://docker.com y donde puedes encontrar los repos oficiales: https://hub.docker.com/explore/